# How to place a button Exact below the Textview

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, uitextview

I am having two labels and  one textview which i am using to show the parsing data from json. Here i am increasing the labels and textview heights based on the text . Now i want to place a button below the textview like i want to calculate both labels and textview heights and place a button exact below the textview.
How to achieve this?

Comment: @user337798 use this "yourtextfieldname.bounds.size.height"    "yourtextfieldname.bounds.size.width"

Comment: btn.frame = cgrectmake(btn.frame.origin.x, textview.frame.origin.y + textview.frame.size.height + 10 ,btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size.height);

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat y = label1.frame.origin.y + label1.frame.size.height;
label2.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

y = label2.frame.origin.y + label2.frame.size.height;
txtView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

y = txtView.frame.origin.y + txtView.frame.size.height;
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```